# Parser syntax errors when trying to install Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting a ton of errors trying to install Rails 3.1.1.  The error looks something like this:

```
Building YARD (yri) index for rack-test-0.6.1...
[error]: ParserSyntaxError: syntax error in `README.rdoc`:(1,1): syntax error, unexpected '='
[error]: Stack trace:
    /Users/Philly/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/yard-0.7.3/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:505:in `on_parse_error'
    /Users/Philly/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/yard-0.7.3/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:49:in `parse'
    /Users/Philly/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/yard-0.7.3/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:49:in `parse'
    /Users/Philly/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/yard-0.7.3/lib/yard/parser/ruby/ruby_parser.rb:15:in `parse'
    /Users/Philly/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/yard-0.7.3/lib/yard/parser/source_parser.rb:438:in `parse'
    /Users/Philly/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/yard-0.7.3/lib/yard/parser/source_parser.rb:361:in `parse_in_order'
```

This error crops up for a whole bunch of gems though. The gems I have in my rvm global gemset are:

```
bundler (1.0.21)
coderay (0.9.8)
method_source (0.6.6)
pry (0.9.6.2)
pry-doc (0.3.0)
rake (0.9.2.2)
ruby_parser (2.0.6)
sexp_processor (3.0.7)
slop (2.1.0)
yard (0.7.3)
```

And this is an empty gemset that I try to install Rails to so I'm not really sure what's going on but I assume it has something to do with yard or ruby_parser?

Any help getting rid of these errors would be much appreciated, unless it's one of those things that don't really affect anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current version of rack-test gem isn't configured properly to generate ri doc.
Try to install rails with --no-ri option.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore these errors; these non-source files are just being skipped. Newer versions of yard [won't generate these errors](https://github.com/lsegal/yard/issues/541).